# Trying to get property 'approval_code' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a task scheduler for sending email routine and i got this error when i try to get `approval_code` from auth.

Here are my code in mail:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Services\GetApprovalPersonByRouteCode;
use App\HabisKontrak;

class HabisKontrakMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     * @param HabisKontrak $habisKontrak
     * @param [type] $person
     * @param [type] $justInfo
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
        // $this->link = $link;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $reminder_kontrak=HabisKontrak::all();
        $person = GetApprovalPersonByRouteCode::getPerson(auth()->user()->approval_code,HabisKontrak::KODE_MODUL);
        return $this->subject('Pemberitahuan Karyawan Habis Kontrak')
                    ->view('mail.reminder.habisKontrak')
                    ->with([
                        'reminder_kontrak' => $reminder_kontrak,
                        'person' => $person
                    ]);
        // }
    }
}
```

and here are code for the `GetApprovalPersonByRouteCode`

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use DB;
use App\PermintaanKendaraan;

class GetApprovalPersonByRouteCode{
    /**
     * Get person approval / just info
     *
     * @param string $approvalCode
     * @param string $kode_modul
     * @return void
     */
    public static function getPerson($approvalCode, $kode_modul){
       return DB::table('approvalroutedetail')
        ->select([
            'approvalroutedetail.nik',
            'approvalroutedetail.sequence',
            'approvalroutedetail.just_info',
            'approvalroutedetail.modul',
            'approvalroutedetail.approvalroute_id',
            'karyawan.nama',
            'karyawan.departemensubsub',
            'karyawan.email',
            'karyawan.jabatan'
        ])->join('karyawan','approvalroutedetail.nik','karyawan.nik')
        ->where('approvalroutedetail.modul', $kode_modul)
        ->where('approvalroutedetail.approvalroute_id', $approvalCode)
        ->orderBy('approvalroutedetail.sequence','asc')
        ->orderBy('approvalroutedetail.just_info','asc')
        ->get();
    }
}
```

I tried to pass the data via constructor like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Services\GetApprovalPersonByRouteCode;
use App\HabisKontrak;
use App\Reminder;
use DateTime;

class HabisKontrakMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    protected $person; //approver (collection: GetApprovalPersonByRouteCode::getPerson)
    
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     * @param HabisKontrak $habisKontrak
     * @param [type] $person
     * @param [type] $justInfo
     *
     */
    public function __construct($person)
    {
        //
        $this->person = $person;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $reminder_kontrak=HabisKontrak::all();
        return $this->subject('Pemberitahuan Karyawan Habis Kontrak')
                    ->view('mail.reminder.habisKontrak')
                    ->with([
                        'reminder_kontrak' => $reminder_kontrak,
                        'person' => $this->person
                    ]);
        // }
    }
}
```

And then i got the error massage

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Mail\HabisKontrakMail::__construct(), 0 passed

I try to get this value `getPerson(auth()->user()->approval_code,HabisKontrak::KODE_MODUL)`, Thankyou.

Comment: you cannot access auth()->user in a queue, you need to pass the id or approval code in the constructor.

Comment: @GertB. I tried to pass the approval code in constructor but i got this error "Too few arguments to function App\Mail\HabisKontrakMail::__construct(), 0 passed"

Comment: Do you pass it where you call new HabisKontrakMail()? ( new HabisKontrakMail(auth()->user()->approval_code) )

Comment: @GertB. to commands for task scheduler, but i dont know how to pass it to app\Console\Commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task scheduler does not have a user session, thus `auth()->user()` can only return `null` (non-object).

To fix this, your crontab command can provide the user argument along. And your command can get a user with [arguments](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#arguments):

> ### Arguments
>
> All user supplied arguments and options are wrapped in curly braces. In the following example, the command defines one required argument: `user`:
>
> ```php
> /**
>  * The name and signature of the console command.
>  *
>  * @var string
>  */
> protected $signature = 'mail:send {user}';
> ```
>
> You may also make arguments optional or define default values for arguments:
>
> ```php
> // Optional argument...
> mail:send {user?}
>
> // Optional argument with default value...
> mail:send {user=foo}
> ```

Simply pass the load a `User` object with the `user` argument (probably the user id or the user name). Pass this `User` on to `HabisKontrakMail` object, then you're good to go.

### Wait. Doesn't that mean the same user is sending every time?

One catch is you can only have 1 user sending all the notification email. But according to the code you showed, the database don't seem to contain which user actually initiated the notification.

If you need to actually check it, you'll have to store the user id / username for the notification *before* it is scheduled. And I don't have enough information to suggest anything.

Comment: Do i need add it to construct in `HabisKontrakMail` or `Commands`?

Comment: I tried to add it to construct in `HabisKontrakMail` and i get this error  `local.ERROR: Aborted. {"exception":"[object]`

Comment: You need to add this to your `Command` implementation. Then you need to provide this to `HabisKontrakMail` object. Since you've shown no code of the actual command, I don't exactly know how you are going to do it.